# Doesn't type parameter play any role?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have a generic class Parcel and a generic method deliver shown in the below code. The method prints and returns x which is assigned a type parameter Integer inside the method.

```java
public class Parcel<T> {
    public <X> X deliver(){
        X x = (X) new Integer(100);
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Inside the main I call the method deliver by passing a type parameter Parcel. However it still prints 100.

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Parcel<String> parcel = new Parcel<>();
    System.out.println(parcel.<Parcel> deliver());
}
```

This follows that the type argument Parcel passed in the print line doesn't play any role, and I expected an exception here. How does it work ?

Comment: Because you're binding to `java.lang.Object`. `X` is not bound to any particular type assuming it's upper bound is `java.lang.Object`, so there is no `ClassCastException`. You'll get one, if you invoke `deliver` and cast the result to a variable/field/parameter that have other types than `java.lang.Object`, `java.lang.Number`, and `java.lang.Integer`. And your code doesn't fail because you invoke `println(Object)`. If you change it to `parcel.<String>deliver()`, the compiler will use `println(String)` that will result in `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: Also, you can change your `<X>` constraint to a more concrete type, and the compiler will use conrete type cast in your `deliver()` method. Say, `<X extends String>` would result in `ClassCastException` for this line: `X x = (X) (Object) new Integer(100);` because `X` is replaced with `java.lang.String` here.

Answer (score 1):

What you observe is called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Generic parameters are used by compiler to ensure type correctness and does not present in run-time.

Generally speaking nothing stops you from doing this trick:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.append(""); // produces compiler error

// just drop that "useless" generic argument
List erased = (List) list;
erased.append(""); // works fine
```

**EDIT**

Actually my original answer occasionally was for this `Parcel` implementation

```java
public class Parcel<T> {
    public T deliver(){
        T x = (T) new Integer(100);
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

But the key idea is the same for `<X> X deliver()`:

```java
Object parcel = parcel.<Parcel> deliver(); // erased, works ok
Parcel parcel = parcel.<Parcel> deliver(); // java.lang.ClassCastException
```